# How do I clear the scene in kiss3d?

Tags: rust

This a specific question about sebcrozet/kiss3d (a graphics package for games written in rust): how do I clear the 'scene'?

I can add objects to the scene by `window.add_mesh()` and similar methods, and it seems I can remove specific objects by `windows.remove_node()`, but how do I remove all the objects in a scene (e.g. to start a new scene)?

I suppose I could keep a vector of all the objects in the scene, and then iterate over the vector to remove the objects, but that should not be necessary.

*Edit: here is some code that reproduces the error, excerpted from my code.*

```
use kiss3d::resource::Mesh;
use kiss3d::window::Window;
use na::Point3;
use na::Vector3;
use rand::Rng;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

extern crate kiss3d;
extern crate nalgebra as na;
extern crate rand;

fn main() {
    let mut window = Window::new("Test");
    const FRAMES_PER: u16 = 100;
    let mut frame_count = FRAMES_PER;
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    window.set_point_size(5.0);

    while window.render() {
        frame_count += 1;

        if frame_count > FRAMES_PER {
            window
                .scene_mut()
                .apply_to_scene_nodes_mut(&mut |n| n.unlink());
            let mut vertexes: Vec<Point3<f32>> = vec![];
            let mut indexes: Vec<Point3<u16>> = vec![];
            vertexes.push(Point3::new(
                rng.gen_range(-500.0, 500.0),
                rng.gen_range(-500.0, 500.0),
                400.0,
            ));
            vertexes.push(Point3::new(
                rng.gen_range(-500.0, 500.0),
                rng.gen_range(-500.0, 500.0),
                400.0,
            ));
            vertexes.push(Point3::new(
                rng.gen_range(-500.0, 500.0),
                rng.gen_range(-500.0, 500.0),
                400.0,
            ));
            indexes.push(Point3::new(0, 1, 2));

            let mesh = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Mesh::new(
                vertexes, indexes, None, None, false,
            )));
            let mut c = window.add_mesh(mesh, Vector3::new(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));

            c.set_color(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            c.enable_backface_culling(false);
            frame_count = 0;
            println!("scene regenerated");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do `window.remove (window.scene())`?

Comment: No, as I said in my reply to Akiner Alkan, I get `cannot borrow 'window' as mutable more than once at a time`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a `scene` from a `window` with the [`Window::scene_mut`](http://kiss3d.org/doc/kiss3d/window/struct.Window.html#method.scene_mut) function, which will return a [`SceneNode`](http://kiss3d.org/doc/kiss3d/scene/struct.SceneNode.html).

After you get your mutable scene node you can delete all the objects inside of the scene with the [`SceneNode::apply_to_scene_nodes`](http://kiss3d.org/doc/kiss3d/scene/struct.SceneNode.html#method.apply_to_scene_nodes_mut) function.

As documented in kiss3d docs page:

> `fn apply_to_scene_nodes_mut<F: FnMut(&mut SceneNode)>(&mut self, f: &mut F)`
>
> Applies a closure to each object contained by this node and its children.

This is the method that takes closure in it and applies it to the all nodes inside to scene. So you don't need to add all the objects to a `Vec`.

Note that this method is working recursively to apply the function you provided to all the childrens of the parent and itself.

In your case it is only needed to unlink the parent scene like following:

```
window.scene_mut().unlink();
```

Whenever you unlink the parent scene node, then the children will be unlinked with the parent of course. So in your needs you may not need to 
`SceneNode::apply_to_scene_nodes` even.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=349f26015fe13743d8ec1d9601f6e160)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have coded `window.scene_mut().apply_to_scene_nodes_mut(&mut |n| n.unlink());` but that crashes with `'already borrowed: BorrowMutError'`. If I use `window.remove_node(n)` the compiler says `cannot borrow 'window' as mutable more than once at a time`.

Comment: Could you please share the work that you have tried so maybe we can identify that problem.

Comment: I've added some code to the question that shows the behaviour.

Comment: @MartinEllison Updated your code and my answer. This way, the problem seems solved :) Good luck

Comment: Sorry, I've run the code in your playground link, and it does not delete anything. It should be displaying only one triangle at any time, but just keeps adding new triangles and not deleting any. I am at `kiss3d = "0.18.0"`, if that is relevant.

Comment: OK, I think I have it working. The new code is at https://gist.github.com/rust-play/b301f7d04de8eb83e537960c045ecb0c . Anyway, what I did was `let mut old_group = window.add_group();` before the main loop, `old_group.unlink();` to do the actual deletion and `let mut ng = window.add_group();  let mut c = ng.add_mesh(mesh, Vector3::new(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)); old_group = ng;` to add the mesh and cache the group. (There are also improvements to the graphics code but they do not affect the subject of this question).